# Cant install Rich python module

Tags: python, installation, pip

I'm not being able to install Rich module. (I use RPIos a debian distribution btw)
I used the pip methodd to insttall rich. My comand was: pip install rich.
Here is the error:

pi@Andres:~ $ sudo pip install rich

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting rich
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rich (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for rich

Sorry if this question is stupid i'm new to linux.

Comment: check this https://blog.csdn.net/wwwithin/article/details/104103944

Comment: Just as a tip you shouldn't install a pip package as sudo

Answer (score 0):

If this module is what you wanted: https://github.com/Textualize/rich, then you can go ahead and install via

```
python -m pip install rich
```